# Setting up the test execution sequence in conftest.py of pytest, parametrized testing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest, parametrized-testing

*conftest.py:*

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    def param_part(item):
        # check for the wanted module and test class
        if item.nodeid.startswith("test_urls.py::TestSSL::"):
            # find the start of the parameter part in the nodeid
            index = item.nodeid.find('[')
            if index > 0:
                # sort by parameter name
                return item.name[item.nodeid.index('['):]

        # for all other cases, sort by node id as usual
        return item.nodeid

    # re-order the items using the param_part function as key
    items[:] = sorted(items, key=param_part)
```

*test_urls.py:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
import pytest
import logging
import allure


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')


# Logger

logging.basicConfig(filename="C:/LPsLogs/test.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

ec = EC
goxp = driver.find_element_by_xpath
goid = driver.find_element_by_id
keys = Keys
original_window = driver.current_window_handle

# Urls
sslurl = "https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html"

# Locators

# xpath
sslpch = "//h1"
u1chb1 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[1]"
u1chb2 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[3]"
u1chb3 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[5]"
u1chb4 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[7]"
u1chb5 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[11]"
u1chb6 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[15]"

# id
hostname = "hostname"
expdate = "cert_expiration_days"


@allure.severity(allure.severity_level.BLOCKER)
def test_go_ca_sslcheck():
    logger.info("Testing started")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(sslurl)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, sslpch)))
    sslchecker = driver.find_element_by_xpath(sslpch).text
    if sslchecker == 'SSL Checker':
        assert True
    else:
        logging.error('Error - def test_go_sslcheck module', exc_info=True)
        allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
        assert False



@pytest.mark.parametrize("url", ["https://google.com",
                                 "https://expired.badssl.com"
                                 ])
class TestSSL:
    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_input(self, url):
        try:
            input_hostname = goid(hostname)
            input_hostname.send_keys(url)
            input_hostname.send_keys(keys.ENTER)
            # time.sleep(2)
            print(f"{url} has been entered")
            assert True
            input_hostname.clear()
        except (Exception, NameError, AssertionError):
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error('Error - url_input module', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox1(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb1)))
        u1chb1ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb1).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb1ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox1 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 1 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox2(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb2)))
        u1chb2ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb2).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb2ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox2 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 2 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox3(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb3)))
        u1chb3ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb3).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb3ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox3 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 3 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox4(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb4)))
        u1chb4ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb4).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb4ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox4 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 4 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox5(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb5)))
        u1chb5ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb5).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb5ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox5 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 5 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox6(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb6)))
        u1chb6ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb6).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb6ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox6 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 6 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.NORMAL)
    def test_url_expdate_w(self, url):
        expdatech = driver.find_element_by_id(expdate).text
        if int(expdatech) > 7:
            print(f"{url} - expdate more than 7 days - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            print(expdatech)
            logging.warning(f"{url} SSL certificate will expire in less than 7 days, days left: {expdatech}", exc_info=True)
            assert False


# def test_close_browser():
    try:
        logger.info("Testing finished")
        driver.close()
        assert True
    except (Exception, NameError, AssertionError):
        logging.error('Error - close_browser module', exc_info=True)
        assert False
```

**Result:**
Test execution sequence **now** - https://prnt.sc/ttw4or
Also conftest sorts tests by name (alphabet), I need to remove this dependency.

**Target result:**
test execution sequence **needed** - test_go_ca_sslcheck() > class iteration with first url > class iteration with next url, until their over > def test_close_browser()

**Note:**
Perhaps there is an easier way to achieve the goal, please describe in detail, my knowledge is extremely limited. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood that correctly now, you don't want to change the default sort order, except for the parametrized tests.
Here is a slightly more complicated adapted version that shall do this (I tried to add enough comments to explain it):

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    def param_part(item):
        index = item.name.find('[')
        if index > 0:
            # revert the name and parameter parts, so tests are sorted by
            # parameter first and name second
            return (item.name[item.name.index('['):]
                    + item.name[:item.name.index('[')])
        return item.name

    class_id = "test_urls.py::TestSSL::"
    # find the first test in the class to be sorted
    start_index = next((i for (i, item) in enumerate(items)
                        if item.nodeid.startswith(class_id)), -1)
    if start_index != -1:
        # ... and the first test after the class
        # (have to start the first at start_index)
        end_index = next((i + start_index for (i, item)
                          in enumerate(items[start_index:])
                          if not item.nodeid.startswith(class_id)), -1)
        # sort only the items in the class and let the rest alone
        items[start_index:end_index] = sorted(items[start_index:end_index],
                                              key=param_part)
    # for any other tests without our class we leave the items alone
```

This gives the output for `pytest -vv test_urls.py`:

```
...
test_urls.py::test_go_ca_sslcheck PASSED                                                                         [  5%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox1[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 11%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox2[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 16%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox3[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 22%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox4[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 27%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox5[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 33%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox6[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 38%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_expdate_w[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                     [ 44%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_input[https://expired.badssl.com] PASSED                                         [ 50%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox1[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 55%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox2[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 61%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox3[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 66%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox4[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 72%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox5[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 77%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_checkbox6[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 83%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_expdate_w[https://google.com] PASSED                                             [ 88%]
test_urls.py::TestSSL::test_url_input[https://google.com] PASSED                                                 [ 94%]
test_urls.py::test_close_browser PASSED                                                                          [100%]

================================================= 18 passed in 0.16s ==================================================
```

Comment: With this conftest it works fine. But I can not comment tests (for example if I will comment last test "def test_close_browser()" - result 17\17 failed, screens of errors: [link](https://prnt.sc/tu4ebz), [link](https://prnt.sc/tu4ekk)). @MrBean, can you explain why comments are not allowed and is there easy way to fix it? 
   For other beginners like me - I should note that tests in class runs performed in alphabetical order of names.

Comment: Maybe you did not comment out the test but only the definition line like in your example? You have to comment out the whole test, of course.